# Python3.3: .format() with unicode format_spec

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

I have datetime object and my users provide their own format string to format the time in the way they like.

One way I find is to use `'{:...}'.format(mydatetime)`.

```
lt = time.localtime(time.time())
d = datetime. datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(lt))
print(userString.format(datetime=d))
```

English users may provide `'{datetime:%B %d, %Y}'`, which formats to December 24, 2013.

Chinese users may provide `'{datetime:%Y年%m月%d日}'` (in YYYYMMDD format, 年=Year, 月=Month, 日=Day).

But when executing `'{datetime:%Y年%m月%d日}'.format(datetime=d)`, Python raises UnicodeEncodingError:
*'locale' codec can't encode character '\u5e74' in position 2: Illegal byte sequence*

I know there is a workaround that I can tell my Chinese users to give format string like `'{datetime:%Y}年{datime:%m}月{datetime:%d}日'`, but cannot unicode character show in format_spec? How to solve this problem?

I'm using Windows.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `import sys; sys.getdefaultencoding()`?

Comment: In PY3 `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is always UTF-8. Use `locale.getlocale()` to get the current locale for the `LC_CTYPE` category, which is what `wcstombs` uses.

Comment: @SimeonVisser sys.getdefaultencoding() returns utf-8.

Comment: @eryksun I'm new to Python. Do you mean `locale.getlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE)` ? It returns `(None, None)`.

Comment: Yes, I use Windows. After `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, 'chinese')`, `'{datetime:%Y年%m月%d日}'` runs well. Besides, I can also put Japanese characters in format_spec. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime.__format__` calls `datetime.strftime`, which does some preprocessing and then calls [`time.strftime`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3896275c0f6/Modules/timemodule.c#l542) (CPython 3.3.3 source).

On Windows, `time.strftime` uses the C runtime's multibyte-string function `strftime` instead of the wide-character string function `wcsftime`. First it has to encode the format string according to the current locale by calling [`PyUnicode_EncodeLocale`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3896275c0f6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l3319). This in turn calls the CRT function [`wcstombs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (MSDN), which uses the currently configured locale for the `LC_CTYPE` category. If the process is currently using the default "C" locale, `wcstombs` converts Latin-1 (codes < 256) directly to bytes, and anything else is an `EILSEQ` error, i.e. "Illegal byte sequence".

Use the locale module to set a new locale. The actual locale names vary by platform, but with Microsoft's [`setlocale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you should be able to just set a [language string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and use the default codepage for the given language. Generally you shouldn't mess with this for a library, and an application should configure the locale at startup. For example:

```
>>> import datetime, locale

>>> oldlocale = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, None)
>>> oldlocale
'C'
>>> newlocale = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, 'chinese')

>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> '{datetime:%Y\\u5e74%m\\u6708%d\\u65e5}'.format(datetime=d)
'2013\\u5e7412\\u670825\\u65e5'
```

If you want the formatted time to use locale-specific names (e.g. month and day), then also set the `LC_TIME` category:

```
>>> newlocale = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'chinese')
>>> '{datetime:%B %d, %Y}'.format(datetime=d)              
'\u5341\u4e8c\u6708 25, 2013'
```